Problem displaying images stored locally in the backend
The problem
In the frontend, I am trying to display the images of what is a publication that contains title, description and their corresponding images. Here I print what I receive and store in posts:
{
  "author": "665a4652de574bc58a89045d",
  "comments": [],
  "createdAt": "2024-05-31T21:55:24.427Z",
  "description": "Primera publicación de prueba",
  "hashtags": ["665a474cde574bc58a8904c1"],
  "images": ["5a6830b0-c395-4340-abed-0bf1cbc03486.jpg"],
  "interactions": [],
  "status": true,
  "title": "Hola mundo",
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "665a474cde574bc58a8904c3"
} 

Frontend component PostViewer.jsx
This is the code I am using to view the posts, I can see the title and description but the image does not
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getPosts } from "@/services/post.service";

const PostViewer = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  const getDataPosts = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await getPosts();
      console.log(response.data.data);
      setPosts(response.data.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching posts:", error);
    }
  };

  const showPosts = () => {
    return posts.map((post) => (
      <div key={post._id}>
        <h1>{post.title}</h1>
        <p>{post.description}</p>
        <div>
          {(post.images || []).map((image, index) => (
            <img
              key={index}
              src={`../../../backend/src/uploads/images/${image}`}
              alt={`Image ${index + 1}`}
              style={{ width: '200px', height: 'auto', margin: '10px' }} 
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    ));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getDataPosts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      PostViewer
      {Array.isArray(posts) && posts.length > 0 ? showPosts() : <p>No posts available</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostViewer;

Backend
In the backend part I use the following controller:
async function getPosts(req, res){
 try {
   const [posts, errorPosts] = await PostService.getPosts();
   if(errorPosts) return [null, "post.controller->errorPosts-> Error searching for posts"];
     posts.length === 0
     ? respondSuccess(req, res, 200, "No existing posts")
     : respondSuccess(req, res, 200, { message: "The following posts were found", data: posts});
 } catch (error) {
 handleError(error, "post.controller -> getPosts");
 respondError(req, res, 500, "post.controller-> Post search error");
}
}

Which uses this service to return publication information:
async function getPosts() {
 try{
   const posts = await Post.find()
   if(!posts) return [null, "No posts found"];
   return[posts, null];
 }catch(error){
 handleError(error, "post.service -> getPosts");
 }
}

I was browsing and they recommended me to use this in my server.js configuration
server.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads/images')));

And then use this in the component PostViewer.jsx:
src={`http://localhost:3000/uploads/images/${image}`}

